# Manually Converting Password and Salt to Compare with ASPNETDB Password

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, hash

I'm trying to manually compare the aspnetdb password field with a manually-hashed password on my end to check for validity (I can't use the default Membership implementation as I'm using a custom one). Anyway, I'm taking the Base64 password salt from the record, and using the following algorithm to get the salted hash:

```
static byte[] GenerateSaltedHash(byte[] plainText, byte[] salt)
{
HashAlgorithm algorithm = new SHA256Managed();

byte[] plainTextWithSaltBytes =
    new byte[plainText.Length + salt.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < plainText.Length; i++)
{
    plainTextWithSaltBytes[i] = plainText[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < salt.Length; i++)
{
    plainTextWithSaltBytes[plainText.Length + i] = salt[i];
}

byte[] hash = algorithm.ComputeHash(plainTextWithSaltBytes);

return hash;
}
```

I then take those bytes and compare with a Convert.GetBase64Bytes(MembershipUser.Password). There's a disconnect somewhere though as the bytes I get from the Convert method and my computed hash are never the same even when I know the passwords are the same.

Any insight on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You can save yourself some code and possible errors by using `Array.CopyTo` to concat the two byte arrays:

byte[] plainTextWithSaltBytes = new byte[plainText.Length + salt.Length];
plainText.CopyTo(plainTextWithSaltBytes, 0);
salt.CopyTo(plainTextWithSaltBytes, plainText.Length);

Answer (score 0):

In looking at the source for SqlMembershipProvider, it appears that they copy the salt *before* the password:

```
static byte[] GenerateSaltedHash(byte[] plainText, byte[] salt)
{
HashAlgorithm algorithm = new SHA256Managed();

byte[] plainTextWithSaltBytes = new byte[plainText.Length + salt.Length];
salt.CopyTo(plainTextWithSaltBytes, 0);
plainText.CopyTo(plainTextWithSaltBytes, salt.Length); 

byte[] hash = algorithm.ComputeHash(plainTextWithSaltBytes);

return hash;
}
```